# Verify $X$ is a direct sum of $V$ and $W$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let 
$$\begin{align*}
X&=\mathcal{C}[0,1],\\
V&=\{v\in \mathcal{C}[0,1]\mid v(x)=v(-x)\},\\
W&=\{w\in\mathcal{C}[0,1]\mid w(x)=-w(-x)\}.
\end{align*}$$
Is it possible to verify that $X$ is a direct sum of $V$ and $W$? Someone help me...

> **Definition:** $X$ is said to be the direct sum of $V$ and $W$ if $u\in X$ has a unique representation $u=v+w$ where  $v\in V$ and $w\in W$.

Comment: $v(x)=v(-x)$ for functions defined on $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Your definitions make no sense: if $x\in [0,1]$, then $-x\in [0,1]$ if and only if $x=0$. Did you mean $\mathcal{C}[-1,1]$? If so, you are asking whether every continuous function can be decomposed (uniquely) as a sum of an even function and an odd function.

Comment: I think the question is wrong set as I doubt, I dont know how to fix it..

Comment: Well, the definitions are certainly nonsensical...

Answer (score 1):

Everything would make sense if we consider $[-1,1]$ instead of $[0,1]$. The result means that we can write in a unique way a (continuous) function as a sum of an even and a odd continuous functions. To see that, write 
$$u(x)=\underbrace{\frac{u(x)+u(-x)}2}_{=: v(x)}+\underbrace{\frac{u(x)-u(-x)}2}_{=:w(x)}.$$

Comment: One down, [20.780 to go](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered) :-/